# Symfony Dynamic Form Modification based on Submitted Data of another field

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, symfony-forms, symfony5

I've followed the dynamic form modification doc and have run into an issue where it won't allow me to set the `data` option for a specific field dynamically (based on submitted data of another field). It's to my understanding that `POST_SUBMIT` won't allow you to update the data, hence why it won't work; and you can't get the selected data before `POST_SUBMIT`.

**Question: What's the best way around this?**

**What I'm trying to do:** When you select an option in the `subcategory` field, it will update the `data` for the `rating` field based on the option selected in the `subcategory` field.

Here is a demo app made specifically for this issue: https://github.com/rwkt/demo-dynamicform

Dynamic form modification doc: https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#dynamic-generation-for-submitted-forms

Comment: Why don't you use PRE_SET_DATA or POST_SET_DATA? https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/5.1/src/Symfony/Component/Form/FormEvents.php

Comment: The form doesn't know what `subcategory` you selected until the event `POST_SUBMIT` - and considering this, you can't change the `data` of another field (`rating`) in `POST_SUBMIT`. Am I mistaken in this? I've not been able to make it work with `PRE_SET_DATA` and `POST_SET_DATA`.

Comment: I wonder, why you want to set `data` on the form field, when you could change the submitted values (i.e. add/modify the rating value) in PRE_SUBMIT

Comment: I'm trying to display the new form `data` without a page refresh (when you select a subcategory, an ajax post request is triggered to return the new rating form field value - the issue is that you can't dynamically change `data` but you can add/remove fields).